# MIDI parsing - how to know what 0xFF byte designates?

Tags: parsing, midi

I'm just writing my own MIDI parser and I was wondering how to distinguish `0xFF` that designates the complete Real-Time category message `Reset` from the beginning of some `Meta-event` also coded with `0xFF` and then some bytes (for example `FF 2F 00` -> `End of track`).

Comment: You're talking about parsing MIDI files, not straight MIDI data, yes?

Comment: Sorry for being out for some (looong) time. Yes, my aim is to parse a MIDI file, but is there really a difference? I believe the Real-Time category message can be encountered also in a file (I haven't found any source that says it can't, if it is so, please let me now). And as I understand the Real-Time messages can occur at any time, event when you're in the middle of parsing some other command, that's why I don't know how to distinguish both situations.

Answer (score 2):

On a **MIDI cable**, MIDI *messages* are transmitted at the instant they are intended to take place. A **MIDI file** is effectively a recording of timestamped MIDI messages for playback at a later time. The combination of a timestamp and a MIDI message is called an *event*. There are some differences between messages that appear on a MIDI cable and events that appear in a MIDI file.

You're correct that on a MIDI cable, the one-byte Real-Time messages can occur in the middle of bytes of other messages. However, in a MIDI file, keeping track of the exact number of bytes for each event is important, so Real-Time messages can't be stored in a MIDI file in the middle of other events.

System Exclusive events are useful to store in a MIDI file, but in general, it doesn't make sense to store any of the other System Common or System Real-Time messages in a MIDI file.

- **$FF Reset:** In a MIDI cable, the status byte $FF means Reset. However, when you are playing a MIDI file, resetting the receiving MIDI device during playback generally doesn't make sense. So in a MIDI file, a status byte of $FF is redefined to indicate a Meta Event.
- **$F6 Tune Request:** If a device responds to this message, I think it does some internal tuning calibration that would interrupt any playback in progress. So similar to the Reset message, it doesn't make sense to interrupt the playback inside of a MIDI file.
- **Clock, position, and start/stop messages** ($F1 MIDI Time Code Quarter Frame, $F2 Song Position Pointer, $F3 Song Select, $F8 Clock, $FA Start, $FB Continue, $FC Stop): A device or software that records a MIDI file typically won't record these incoming messages into the MIDI file. However, the device may have an option to interpret these messages to actually reposition, start, stop, or control the speed of the playback or recording. A device or software that plays a MIDI file may have options to send these messages to the MIDI output port to control other MIDI devices that are playing their own parts in addition to the MIDI file notes. Because of this usage, the MIDI player is responsible for sending these clock, position, and start/stop messages, not the MIDI file.
- **$FE Active Sensing:** If a sending device sends this message, it's used as an idle filler to suggest the cable is still connected properly. If receiving device starts seeing Active Sensing messages and then they stop, it can interpret that as a cable getting disconnected and silence hung notes. It's not useful to store idle filler in a MIDI file. And it would be a function of a sending device to send it, not the MIDI file's responsibility.

If you really need to store System Common or System Real-Time messages in a MIDI file, I believe they can be stored in an $F7 event in the MIDI file. My understanding is the data bytes stored in the $F7 event will be transmitted verbatim on the MIDI cable. The [Sonic Spot document](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html) calls this usage of $F7 an "Authorization SysEx" event (scroll to the bottom of the document). The [MIDI Technical Fanatic's Brainwashing Center](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/) document [MIDI File Format](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midifile.htm) calls this usage of $F7 an "Escaped" event (see page "Events in an MTrk"). MIDI sequencer software [Sekaiju](http://openmidiproject.sourceforge.jp/Sekaiju_en.html) calls $F7 a "SysEx (Arbitrary)" event.

---

General caveat: On the [MIDI Manufacturers Association](http://www.midi.org/) site you can find some [official information](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/index.php) (tables and addendums to the standards) or ask questions on the [forum](http://www.midi.org/cgi-bin/forum/forum.pl/). But as you're probably aware, the main content of the [official MIDI standards cost money](http://www.midi.org/store/docsales.php). I haven't purchased them, so my understanding above is based on descriptions from third party websites and general usage of MIDI software. You should always remain aware that third parties might have interpreted something differently than the official standards intended. (For example, Jeff Glatt's MIDI Technical Fanatic's Brainwashing Center document [MIDI Specification](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midispec.htm) says $F9 is a Tick message, but the MMA says that message [$F9 is undefined and reserved](http://www.midi.org/cgi-bin/forum/forum.pl/forum.pl?m-1321861191/). Glatt says [General MIDI program 47 is Orchestral Strings](http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tutr/gm.htm), the MMA says [program 47 is Orchestral Harp](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/gm1sound.php).)

Answer (score 1):

As @Brad hinted, there is a difference as to whether you are parsing streaming MIDI data or reading it from file. Anyways, when you are reading it from file you just need to keep track of which state that you are in. You can encounter 0xff many places in the file, but you need to always know if you are parsing events or variable-length timestamp or something else.

For instance, if you have just parsed a timestamp and encounter 0xff, then it's going to be a meta event.

Also, I've found that the best reference for the MIDI file format is here:

> http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html

Comment: Of course you're right, in MIDI file format it's necessary to keep track of the state you're in (are you about to read deltatime or command code or its parameters), but I read the Real-Time category messages can occur at any moment, even in the middle of some other command. And when I'm in the state I can expect `0xFF` how can I know it's Real-Time message or beginning of code of the command?